# Consume RabbitMQ server messages from Apache Qpid java client ? Which version?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, qpid

I have to consume rabbitmq-server with apache qpid java client (because I have to use apache camel). But I am confused with version of both of them , especially because of amqp protocol supported by each.

Which version can of java client qpid can consume/produce to for exemple the last stable release of rabbitmq-server ? or what is the best pair version possible ?
With wich qpid url format ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://www.rabbitmq.com/interoperability.html) on RabbitMQ's site says that they have tested Qpid 0.6 clients with a RabbitMQ broker, but there are protocol versioning issues described there which you should be clear about. Apparently a subsequent commit to Qpid fixed those issues.

Comment: Hi Brian, your are right. I'm not sure the page is up to date though, because last Qpid version is 0.12 if i'am exact. So I think that yes it is fixed. My question was to find which version of rabbitmq-server has been tested to work with which version java qpid client ? Mostly because of amqp version.

Comment: I have no idea which of the recent versions of the two have been tested, but since they are both supposedly AMQP compliant then you could simply try out the two latest versions of both and see if they can connect and produce/consume together.

Comment: We haven't run any tests since that page was written.  The current RabbitMQ broker is fully 0-9-1 compliant, so if you can find a version of QPid that speaks 0-9-1 it should work (assuming they didn't muck up the framing for some methods, which, iirc, they did).  The last time I checked, they were actively dropping support for 0-9-1, so I suspect older releases would be more useful than newer ones.

Comment: Thank you Scvalex, with that information i'll continue to investigate how to reach the good version of qpid. Is there any protocol negociation involved between server and client ? Or should we configure it in hard in both side ?